# How to convert numeric numbers into a normal date?

Tags: r, date, netcdf

I have got a `netcdf` file to extract some variables from it. the provider told me that the time variable (A) is hours since `1900-01-01 00:00:0.0`. I need to convert this variable to a normal date and write to another txt file.

```
f1 <- open.ncdf("C:\\Users\\data.nc")
# [1] "file C:\\Users\\data.nc has 3 dimensions:"
# [1] "longitude   Size: 2"
# [1] "latitude   Size: 2"
# [1] "time   Size: 2920"
# [1] "file C:\\Users\\data.nc has 5 variables:"
# [1] "short stm[longitude,latitude,time]  Longname:soil textre Missval:-32767"
```

time:

```
A <- get.var.ncdf(nc=f1,varid="time")
head(A)
## [1] 990552 990558 990564 990570 990576 990582
```

another variable:

```
B1 <- get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="stm")
write.table(t(rbind(A,B1)),file="output.txt")
```

I need your help to convert the time variable to a normal date before writing to the text output file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Date**

If `A` are hours since `"1900-01-01"`, just divide them by 24, and pass this date into the `origin` parameter within the `as.Date` function, as in

```
A <- c(990552, 990558, 990564, 990570, 990576, 990582)
as.Date(A/24, origin = "1900-01-01")
## [1] "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-02" "2013-01-02"
```

---

**Date + time**

If you want the hours too, use `as.POSIXct` instead and multiply by 3600 (You should probably specify your time zone too within `tz` parameter)

```
as.POSIXct(A*3600, origin = "1900-01-01")
## [1] "2013-01-01 02:00:00 IST" "2013-01-01 08:00:00 IST" "2013-01-01 14:00:00 IST" "2013-01-01 20:00:00 IST" "2013-01-02 02:00:00 IST" "2013-01-02 08:00:00 IST"
```

---

**Time zone**

In order to know your time zone, type

```
Sys.timezone()
```

For a full list of possible time zones, type

```
OlsonNames()
```

---

**Adding/Removing hours**

Either way, you can remove/add hours by multiplying the number of hours by `3600` and adding/removing from the results, for example

```
as.POSIXct(A*3600, origin = "1900-01-01") - 2*3600
```

Comment: Thanks . these data-sets are provided each 6 hours`00,06,12,18 as you can see we have this date  `2013-01-01`four times. How we can add the hours to the date before writing?

Comment: Use `as.POSIXct("1900-01-01") + A*60*60`.

Comment: Yeah, similarly to @lukeAs comment, I've also updated the answer.

Comment: It is strange,the first date in my data should be `2013-01-01 00:00:00` Do you have an idea why there is a difference in the time? it should be `00,06,12,18`

Comment: Yes, time zone differences. I've said in my answer that you should probably specify it too.

Comment: my time zone is `CET`.Where to add tz?

Comment: You can do either `as.POSIXct(A*3600, origin = "1900-01-01", tz = "CET")` or just `as.POSIXct(A*3600, origin = "1900-01-01") - 7200` (remove two hours. Whatever you prefer. See my edit.

Comment: Last question:I wrote the output as in my question but when i looked at the file I found the date(A) was not written correctly!`"A" "B"
"1" 1356998400`  . `"2013-01-01 02:00:00 IST" was written as 1356998400`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.